# Presenting relationship of rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, presentations, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables named FORM and FORMACTION. The rows in FORM represent screens in a CRM system and FORMACTION represents which FORMs lead to which. e.g.

```
FORM
ID,NAME,LNAME
1,"CustomerD","Enter customer details"
2,"AddressD","Enter address details"

FORMACTION
ID,FORMID,DESTID
1,1,1
2,1,2
```

What I want is to show these relationships as a map. My first thought was to import to Visio and show them connected as different shapes linking to each other. i.e. each entry in FORM would be a shape with each entry in FORMACTION drawing a line between them. However Visio 2010 doesn't seem to have any import other than for Hierarchal Org chart which is unsuitable as some of these FORMs can both lead to themselves or one FORM can lead to multiple other FORMs.

What are some presentation tools or strategies that could be used to achieve this?

PS: There is about 2000 rows in FORM and 4000 in FORMACTION so any generated result is likely to be a confusing mess. This is acceptable.

Comment: And the database diagram within SQL management studio won't suffice?

Comment: @Dave AFAIK the Database Diagram in SSMS allows you to show the relationship between Tables, not between Rows. If I'm wrong can you advise the entry point to create what you're referring to?

Comment: I can't test it, I don't have SQL here :(

Comment: I do @Dave, as far as I can see it's for schemas only.